# Getting response: 401 while using /api/projects/create api to create project space in sonarqube and passing payload data using POST method request

Tags: sonarqube

Getting response: 401 while using /api/projects/create api to create project space in sonarqube and passing payload data using POST method request in python script.Please provide the best suggestions to skip this error and create a project space in Sonarqube.And i have admin access for sonarqube.

Comment: 401 means you are not authenticated. So if you think, your user has admin access, you are probably doing the authentication incorrect ... The best and -- well -- only way to resolve this issue, is providing correct credentials for the authentication in whatever way the api expects it

Comment: I am able to login GUI with the same credentials. But in my script it was showing 401 even i used same login's for Bitbucket and i am able to login

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong in your script ... But nobody will know, as you don't show what you are doing ...

Answer (score -1):

You should create a key(My account > Security > user token) and pass it in your request.

Example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<user-token>@<sonar-end-point>/api/projects/create' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'name=api-test' --data-urlencode 'project=api-test' --data-urlencode 'organization=api-plat'
```